# Zend Framework 1.11.12, Doctrine 2.2.2 integration: Error 500

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to integrate Doctrine 2 into Zend Framework (I'm new to ZF). I've look everywhere on the net but couldn't find my answer...

I've followed this recent tutorial: http://hectorpinol.com/zend-framework-1-11-and-doctrine-2-2-x-integration/ and I've managed to generate a table using the CLI.

The last step of the tuto is to add a new line in this table, simply using the Index controller. But my website doesn't work anymore (a brutal error 500, no message) because I changed the bootstrap.

if I remove the last lines I added to the `_initDoctrine()` method, it works again (but without Doctrine of course). Here they are:

```
    // set the proxy dir and set some options
    $config->setProxyDir(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/Proxies');
    $config->setAutoGenerateProxyClasses(true);
    $config->setProxyNamespace('App\Proxies');

    // now create the entity manager and use the connection
    // settings we defined in our application.ini
    $connectionSettings = $this->getOption('doctrine');
    $conn = array(
        'driver'    => $connectionSettings['conn']['driv'],
        'user'      => $connectionSettings['conn']['user'],
        'password'  => $connectionSettings['conn']['pass'],
        'dbname'    => $connectionSettings['conn']['dbname'],
        'host'      => $connectionSettings['conn']['host']
    );
    $entityManager = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($conn, $config);

    // push the entity manager into our registry for later use
    $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
    $registry->entitymanager = $entityManager;

    return $entityManager;
```

Do you have any idea to unlock the situation? It's frustrating because I know I'm so close to make it work...

UPDATE1: I forgot to mention, in case it helps: I'm using WAMP on Windows. Thanks

UPDATE2: Added the parameters of the `create()` function.

UPDATE3: Actually it might not be an error 500. Chrome says this but Firefox just displays nothing. No answer from the server.

Comment: Why did all the comments & answers disappeared??

Comment: Because what I thought was the problem, is not the problem.  You'll need to find someone else who can help.  I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: OK, I was wondering what happened! I'm still looking for my answer. Now I'm trying it on Linux...

Answer (score 0):

1) Change the environment to development to see the error message.

2) Use Bisna library instead, will save a lot of time (I don't see a point in integrating Doctrine manually well only educational purposes but you might want to save it for later).

Comment: Thanks for that advice, I'll try to use that library and give you the feedback. I'm already in development environment. Cheers.

Comment: I'm trying to understand that page about Bisna's library (http://www.kurttest.com/zfa/bisna.html) but the explanation are not clear for me, a beginner. Isn't there an other tuto/explanation available?

Comment: @GuilhemSoulas not really, not much to do with it. Take a look at this Guilherme Blanco's (the guy behind this library) skeleton project at github: https://github.com/guilhermeblanco/ZendFramework1-Doctrine2
You just need to copy Zend folder to library and Doctrine (see application.ini lines 38 - 54 where the Bisna library expects to find the Doctrine).

Comment: I'll have a look this weekend. If it's that easy I should make it work. Cheers.

Comment: I fixed the errors in the Apache log but it's still not ready to work. I suppose I'll be able to do it when I'll know Zend and Doctrine a little bit more.